# Set coloring scheme for Git

Tags: git

I am having trouble with the current Git coloring scheme.

I am using Git client on Windows (8.1) with Bash, Linux (Gentoo and RHEL8) and OSX.

On Windows and RHEL8 the text is written in Red on the Black background, which makes the text almost unreadable.

I was using it on RHEL7, where the text coloring scheme was much better (unfortunately, I don't remember the exact color and the partition is gone now).

On Gentoo where I use slightly outdated client it's OK, but I have another laptop, where coloring scheme is the same - Red text on the Black background.

I also have OSX High Sierra, where the colors are OK.

The easiest way to fix it is on Windows - I just need to set the text color to be white in the Bash window Properties.

But what do I do both Linuxes? And maybe there is an easier way of fixing the color scheme in Bash on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Git allows you to control the use of colors with the various `color.*` options.  Specifically, `color.ui` acts as a default for the other options, and color for various subcommands can be toggled on or off.  You can also control the specific colors used, either as standard color name, a 256-color color ID, or, for terminals which support true color, a hex color code.  All of this is documented in the `git-config(1)` manual page.

Now, the actual colors used depend on the terminal.  Specifically, while generally the 256 color palette and true colors are generally standard, the 16 base colors are highly dependent on the terminal and vary greatly.  You can specify something like "red" and that can vary in shade and intensity, as you [can see on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

By default, Git uses only the standard 16 terminal colors, so those will be dependent on the terminal.  If you see red being used in the same place on different systems, it may be easiest to just configure the terminal colors to shades that are easier to read and distinguish.  Most terminal emulators offer such configuration options, because this is a common thing to adjust.

Otherwise, provided you use a suitable terminal emulator, you may find defining colors using the 256-color palette (which is also mentioned on the Wikipedia page) to work better and be more consistent.  Note that your `TERM` environment variable will typically be set to something ending in `-256color` (e.g., `xterm-256color`, `screen-256color`, or `tmux-256color`), although some terminals, such as the one used in WSL (`ms-terminal`) have always supported 256 colors and therefore won't have such a suffix.

Comment: I understand. What I'd like to know is how to set the colors. On Wndows as I sad - I'm using `bash`. On both Linux and OSX I use `Termnal` (under GNOME with X11 and Wayland). Is there a command in git to set the colors?

Comment: @Igor: read the `git config` manual page; search for `color`. There's a lot here, it's a big pain to set it all up, but it *is* all documented.